# Error when trying to get access to my remote client from my remote EJB

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, rmi

I've been stuck for two days now, trying to resolve a communication problem between my singleton session bean and a standalone (rmi) client.
Here is the point: I have a remote session bean (LoadBalancer) which can be accessed by a client (ChatRoom), and which can also access to the client... in theory.

The remote interface:

```
public interface ILoadBalancer{

    public void addChatRoom( IChatRoom chatRoom );

    public void removeChatRoom( IChatRoom chatRoom );
}
```

The session bean:

```
@Remote(ILoadBalancer.class)
@Singleton
public class LoadBalancer implements ILoadBalancer {

/**
 * List of available chat rooms
 */
private Map<String, IChatRoom> chatRooms;


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("loadBalancerLogger");

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        chatRooms = new HashMap<String, IChatRoom>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addChatRoom(IChatRoom chatRoom) {
        // Adding a new chat room to the list of available chat rooms
        try {
            chatRooms.put(chatRoom.getName(), chatRoom);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Enregistrement d'un salon de discussion {0}", chatRoom.getName());
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadBalancer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChatRoom(IChatRoom chatRoom) {
        // Removing a chat room from the list of available chat rooms
        try {
            chatRooms.remove(chatRoom.getName());
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Suppression du salon de discussion {0}", chatRoom.getName());
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadBalancer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

These are deployed in a glassfish server (4.1).

And now the standalone client using RMI:

```
public interface IChatRoom extends Remote {

    public int postMessage( String pseudo, String message) throws RemoteException;

    public int subscribe( String pseudo) throws RemoteException;

    public List<String> getNewMessages(String pseudo, int sequenceNumber) throws RemoteException;

    public String getName() throws RemoteException;
}
```

And the class implementing it:

```
public class ChatRoom implements IChatRoom, Serializable {

    private String name;

    private List<String> users;

    private List<String> messages;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("chatRoomLogger");

    /**
     * A reference to the load balancer
     */
    private ILoadBalancer loadBalancer;

    public ChatRoom(String name) throws RemoteException, NamingException {
        this.name = name;
        users = new ArrayList<String>();
        messages = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Making the chat room available via RMI
        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);

        // Retrieving a reference to the loadBalancer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty(Context.STATE_FACTORIES, "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        props.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        loadBalancer = (ILoadBalancer) ctx.lookup("java:global/loadBalancer/LoadBalancer!sn.esp.dgi.core.ILoadBalancer");

        loadBalancer.addChatRoom(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int postMessage(String pseudo, String message) throws RemoteException {
    // Not relevant to the problem
    }

    @Override
    public int subscribe(String pseudo) throws RemoteException {
        // Not relevant to the problem
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getNewMessages(String pseudo, int sequenceNumber) throws RemoteException {
        // Not relevant to the problem
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() throws RemoteException {
        // Not Relevant to the problem
    }
}
```

As you have seen, the client has a remote reference to the session bean, and the session bean has also a remote reference to all the clients that have subscribed to it.

The client is launched with this code:

```
public class ChatRoomLauncher {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        if( args.length < 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java ChatRoomLauncher <nomChatRoom>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String chatRoomName = args[0];

        try {
            IChatRoom chatRoom = new ChatRoom(chatRoomName);
            System.out.println("Salon de discussion "+ chatRoomName +" démarré ");
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatRoomLauncher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatRoomLauncher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

After generating the stub and skeleton of respectively IChatRoom and ChatRoom, and placing the stub of IChatRoom in the directory where is deployed the LoadBalancer, I get the following exceptions which are my nightmares since two days:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException
    at sn.esp.dgi.core._ILoadBalancer_Wrapper.addChatRoom(sn/esp/dgi/core/_ILoadBalancer_Wrapper.java)
    at sn.esp.dgi.server.ChatRoom.<init>(ChatRoom.java:76)
    at sn.esp.dgi.server.ChatRoomLauncher.main(ChatRoomLauncher.java:29)
Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: CORBA INV_OBJREF 1330447539 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.INV_OBJREF: WARNING: 00511203: Class sn.esp.dgi.server.ChatRoom not exported, or else is actually a JRMP stub  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1203  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:260)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at sn.esp.dgi.core.__ILoadBalancer_Remote_DynamicStub.addChatRoom(sn/esp/dgi/core/__ILoadBalancer_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INV_OBJREF: WARNING: 00511203: Class sn.esp.dgi.server.ChatRoom not exported, or else is actually a JRMP stub  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1203  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.objectNotExported(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.Utility.autoConnect(Utility.java:160)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeRemoteObject(Util.java:473)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$12.write(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.writeArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:465)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:196)
    ... 6 more
```

The exception tells me that I have not exported the chatRoom, though I have generated and placed its stub in the directory where I think it should be.
I've tried to change the instruction UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this) by PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(this), but I still get an error, different from this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I succeed in getting a reference of the EJB, partially. If I don't look up its right JNDI name, I get a different and explicit error.
However, the singleton session bean fails in retrieving a reference of the remote client. I really don't know why the error states that the chatroom is not exported...

Comment: Is there anyone who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issues (EJB running on Glassfish 4 server, client with RMI callback object) and finally found a solution! The tricks were to:

1. Make the client implementation inherit from PortableRemoteObject, i.e. in your example:

   ```
   public class ChatRoom extends PortableRemoteObject implements IChatRoom, Serializable
   ```

   Note:
   There were 3 choices for PortableRemoteObject offered by Eclipse:
   javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject  -> did not work, wanted stubs which I did not generate for the client object (error message: java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found)
   com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject -> same issue
   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject -> WORKED, without generating stubs!!
2. Export the object in the constructor (in the same place where you have UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);). Extending the class from com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject allowed simply to use:

   ```
   exportObject(this); // i.e. non-static reference is required
   ```

   Note: if extending from javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject then static reference to PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(this) is needed but then one needs the stub as I've found. You could try that, too, since you have the stubs.

Hope this helps!